# Неправильное поведение опператорв chr и ord

Tags: perl

Вот текст скрипта:

```
#!/usr/bin/perl -w
    print "Укажите путь к файлу: ";
    chomp ($put = <STDIN>);
    open (FILE, "$put") || die $!;
    @text_fila = <FILE>;
    close (FILE);
    open (FILE2, ">>/tmp/w.kr") || $!;
    foreach $stroka (@text_fila)
    {
        @mnogo_sim = split (//, $stroka);
        foreach $zn (@mnogo_sim)
        {
            $zn2 = ord ($zn);
            $zn2 = (((($zn2)**4) + 49)*4/17)-6;
            $zn2 = $zn2." ";
            push (@str2, $zn2);
        }
        push (@str2, "\n");
        print FILE2 @str2;
        @str2 = "";
    }       
    close (FILE2);
    open (FILE, "/tmp/w.kr") || die $!;
    @stroka_kod = <FILE>;
    close (FILE);
    open (FILE2, ">>/tmp/e") || die $!;
    foreach $stroka2 (@stroka_kod)
    {
        @sim_kod = split (/ /, $stroka2);
        pop @sim_kod;
        foreach $sim (@sim_kod)
        {
            $sim = ((($sim+6)*17/4)-49)**(1/4);
            $sim_or = chr ($sim);;
            print $sim,"\t",$sim_or,"\n";           
        }
    }
    close (FILE2);
```

Что делаем? Создаем где-нибудь текст, типа a1\enter\ab2\enter\abc3\enter\abc4
И указываем путь в скрипте. Он кодирует текст (это и есть его цель) и сохраняет файл в закодированном виде. Потом раскодирует и выводит на экран. Когда будет работать нормально - будет возвращать исходный текст до кодировки. Но при выполнении происодит не понятный баг. В частности "49" цифра "1", "50" - то есть "2" выводится тоже как "1", "51" как "2", проверьте сами. Не могу понять почему. Формула исправна, отдельно от скрипта работает.
Скрипт не доделан, но его смысл шифрование текста, и потом расшифровка. Путь файла на выходе значения не имеет я просто поставил /tmp, чтоб не мусорить вам.

Answer (score 1):

Сдается мне функции chr, ord и прочие однобайтовые, в наш век, юникода и прочих двух- и более байтовых надо выкидывать на свалку.

Либо делать окружение скрипта (локаль) принудительно однобайтовым.

Comment: это как? Поясните

Comment: Что как? как установить локаль? Гугл знает )) спросите - perl setlocale posix

либо как вариант весь текст, что вы желаете подать на вход chr/ord - переводите в какой-нибудь cp1251 (Encode::from_to...)